Keep the same l/r-valueness as input type for return type
I tried to implement it as the following, with all of auto, decltype() and std::forward<>().
Is there any simpler implementation?
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
auto foo(T &&t) -> decltype(t) {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v{0, 1};
    vector<int> v0 = foo(v); // OK, copy ctor
    vector<int> &v1 = foo(v); // OK, reference

    vector<int> v2 = foo(vector<int>{0, 1}); // OK, ctor with rvalue
    // vector<int> &v3 = foo(vector<int>{0, 1}); // Error, as expected

    return 0;
}


decltype(auto) foo(T&& t) may be one alternative. It has fewer characters at least :-)

decltype(auto) foo(auto&& t) { return std::forward<decltype(t)>(t); } is even shorter (C++20 for that auto and no template<..>).

@Jarod42 I like this! With it, I can avoid the conflicting deductions of T in template<T> decltype(auto) operator+=(T &&a, const T &b) { a.first += b.first; a.second += b.second; return std::forward<T>(a); } for p0 += p1;. Or do you have solutions still using T?

What are some uses of decltype(auto)?

You can have two Ts. T1 and T2 and they will be deduced independently. That looks like an odd operator+= though.

(T &&a, const std::type_identity_t<T> &b) might be an option to avoid deduction

With that (auto&& t) implementation, maybe in the future, we don't need to write type for function parameters and return type anymore given it's auto everywhere. Just foo(t) { return t; }, like Python. : )
